# How to sample a data.frame to minimise correlation between selected columns?

Tags: r, correlation, sampling

I am trying to subsample a data.frame in a way that the sample would have observations that capture as much variation as possible among a set of columns of the original data.frame.

An example with the `mtcars` dataset: I'd like to find 3 cars that are the most different from each other by `mpg`, `vs` and `carb`. Looking at the data visually, it would probably be Toyota Corolla (high `mpg`, `vs` 1, low `carb`), Cadillac Fleetwood (low `mpg`, `vs` 0, medium `carb`) and either Maserati Bora (low-med `mpg`, `vs` 0, high `carb`) or Ferrari Dino (medium `mpg`, `vs` 0, med-high `carb`):

```r
> mtcars[order(mtcars$mpg),]
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
Camaro Z28          13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
Maserati Bora       15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
Merc 450SLC         15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
AMC Javelin         15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
Dodge Challenger    15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
Ford Pantera L      15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
Merc 450SE          16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
Merc 450SL          17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
Merc 280C           17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Merc 280            19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
Pontiac Firebird    19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
Ferrari Dino        19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Volvo 142E          21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
Toyota Corona       21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
Porsche 914-2       26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
Fiat X1-9           27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
Honda Civic         30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
Lotus Europa        30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
Fiat 128            32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
Toyota Corolla      33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
```

How would I do that programmatically, so that I get a smaller data.frame, e.g.

```
Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
Maserati Bora       15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
Toyota Corolla      33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
```

I was thinking that this can probably be solved with Latin Hypercube Sampling (`lhs` package), but it seems to produce potential data points from a given distribution, rather than giving row indices of the actual dataset.

In addition, what if we also wanted to consider an unordered multi-level factor, e.g. a column `brand`:

```r
> mtcars$brand = factor(sapply(strsplit(rownames(mtcars), " "), function(x)x[[1]]))
> levels(mtcars$brand)
 [1] "AMC"      "Cadillac" "Camaro"   "Chrysler" "Datsun"   "Dodge"   
 [7] "Duster"   "Ferrari"  "Fiat"     "Ford"     "Honda"    "Hornet"  
[13] "Lincoln"  "Lotus"    "Maserati" "Mazda"    "Merc"     "Pontiac" 
[19] "Porsche"  "Toyota"   "Valiant"  "Volvo"
```

Would it need to be decomposed into dummy variables first?

Comment: it seems that you're unsure of what statistic method to use to achieve your desired result. Perhaps posting the question on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) would help you more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the idea by Solarion, Principal Component Analysis can be used for this. The code for getting `ncars` cars using the first principal component and the three columns is:

```r
ncars = 3
df = mtcars[, c("mpg", "vs", "carb")]

PCA1 = prcomp(df, scale.=TRUE)$x[,1]
ResultRows = sort(PCA1)[ceiling(seq(1, length(PCA1), length.out=ncars))]
mtcars[rownames(mtcars) %in% names(ResultRows),]
#>                    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb    brand
#> Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2   Hornet
#> Toyota Corolla    33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1   Toyota
#> Maserati Bora     15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8 Maserati
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

For the more complicated case of including `brand`, we can use Factor Analysis for Mixed Data:

```r
library(FactoMineR)

mtcars$brand = factor(sapply(strsplit(rownames(mtcars), " "), function(x)x[[1]]))

ncars = 3
df = mtcars[, c("mpg", "vs", "carb", "brand")]

PCA1 = FAMD(df, graph=FALSE)$ind$coord[,1]
ResultRows = sort(PCA1)[ceiling(seq(1, length(PCA1), length.out=ncars))]
mtcars[rownames(mtcars) %in% names(ResultRows),]
#>                    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb    brand
#> Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2   Hornet
#> Toyota Corolla    33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1   Toyota
#> Maserati Bora     15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8 Maserati
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure if this is what you are looking for, but here it goes:

1. calculate a distance matrix, giving you information about how "far away" each car is from all other cars, based on all the attributes they have (the default for `dist()` is eucledian, which you can change).
2. Then take the rowsums or colsums (same thing) from that matrix, which just sums up for each car what the combined distance to all other cars is.
3. Then isolate those cars with the biggest distances (here, we want 3 cars)
4. Finally subset your dataframe to only include those cars:

> ```
> distmat <- as.matrix(dist(df))
> distances <- rowSums(distmat)
> mostDistantCars <- tail(sort(distances), 3)
> df2 <- subset(df, rownames(df) %in% names(mostDistantCars))
> ```

Another way could be to cluster the cars and then choose cars from clusters of your choice:

1. Calculate the distance matrix, then do hierarchical clustering.
2. Plot the dendrogram
3. manually choose the cars from a cluster of your choice

> ```
> rowclust <- hclust(dist(df))
>
> devtools::install_github("nicolash2/ggdendroplot")
> library(ggdendroplot)
> library(ggplot2)
>
> ggplot() + geom_dendro(rowclust, pointing = "side", dendrocut = 20)
> df2 <- subset(df, rownames(df) %in% "Maserati Bora")
> ```

[image]

EDIT: The dendrogram is also some shameless self-promotion to my package. Check out all its options at my [dendroplot github page](https://github.com/nicolash2/ggdendroplot).

Comment: The first method produces Fiat 128 (32.4  1    1), Toyota Corolla (33.9  1    1) and Lotus Europa (30.4  1    2). These are the most distant cars from the rest of the dataset, but not the most distant from one another, i.e. they are quite similar between themselves.

The clustering option is a nice idea, but it doesn't allow for automatic determining of which are the most distant clusters/members within a cluster.

Comment: They are the most distant from all cars but themselves. That they are quite similar to each other is coincidence (and is also only true for Fiat128 and ToyoatCorolla, not LotusEuropa). If you want those that are most distant from each other maybe you can do PCA, look at the first dimension and take the max, min and median  value cars.

Comment: Yes, the PCA idea is very nice! Though why only the first dimension? It seems that taking more (proportionally to their influence?) might give better results. Anyway, when I tried this approach, I got Maserati Bora, Hornet Sportabout/Pontiac Firebird (tie due to even number), and Toyota Corolla, which seems reasonable. k-means clustering also tends to put them into separate clusters.

Comment: not exactly sure about this, but maybe taking more PCs will dull the result a little, since PC1 already acounts for the most variance between the cars...and you only have 3 columns from which you do the PCA (mpg, vs, carb). But as I said, I am not sure, so please correct me if I am wrong.